# Find a replacement for Windows' PathAppend on GNU/Linux

Tags: c, linux, path

C programming, are there any good ways to manage path strings rather than using C string API like strcat on linux? The equivalent of Windows' PathAppend would be great. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have windows. So could you explain what magic is performed by `PathAppend` that you don't see by a simple `strcat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick-n-dirty, next-to-untested version that concatenates paths with a Unix-friendly '/' separator between the two:

```
int PathAppend( char* path, char const* more)
{
    size_t pathlen = strlen( path);

    while (*more == '/') {
        /* skip path separators at start of `more` */
        ++more;
    }

    /* 
     * if there's anything to add to the path, make sure there's 
     * a path separator at the end of it
     */

    if (*more && (pathlen > 0) && (path[pathlen - 1] != '/')) {
        strcat( path, "/");
    }

    strcat( path, more);

    return 1; /* not sure when this function would 'fail' */
}
```

Note that in my opinion this function should have a parameter that indicates the destination size.  I also didn't implement the documented functionality that Win32 has of removing "." and ".." components at the start of the path (why is that there?).

Also, what would cause Win32's `PathAppend()` to return failure?

Use (and/or modify) at your own risk...